# Limpar input quando usuário começar a escrever

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde, talvez já exista esta resposta ou esta pergunta. Porém eu não encontrei aqui e nem no google da forma como eu preciso. Achei vários scripts para apagar o campo de um formulário html quando o usuário clica(focus) em um determinado input, porém, o que eu preciso é que o campo com o texto original seja apagado apenas quando o usuário começar a escrever...

alguém pode me ajudar?

obrigado

Comment: E como diferencias "começar a escrever" de um input normal? ou seja se já tem conteúdo quanto tempo tem de passar até ser considerado "começar"? Os campos já vêm preenchidos, é isso? nesse caso um `placeholder` seria mais correto. Explica um pouco melhor e junta código para percebermos o teu problema.

Comment: isso @Sergio, os campos já estão escritos... tipo: <input value="nome"/> ... quando o usuário escrever a primeira letra, esse valor "nome", se apaga...

Comment: Andrei, já testaste usando um placeholder? -> `<input placeholder="nome" />`

Comment: Não... vou testar

Comment: @Sergio, muito obrigado! Nem tinha ouvido falar disso... Abraço!

Comment: Andrei, ótimo, vou juntar uma resposta a falar disso

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solução natural/moderna para isso é usando `placeholder`.

```
 <input placeholder="nome" />
```

Contudo [placeholder é HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) e alguns browsers mais antigos não suportam. Como fazer então? aqui fica uma alternativa:

Se queres usar o `keydown`, ou seja quando o utilizador começar a escrever, podes fazer assim comparando o atributo value com o valor real que ele tem no momento:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    var original = this.getAttribute('value');
    var novo = this.value;
    if (novo == original) this.value = '';
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hh7qqrd7/

O `.getAttribute('value');` é sempre o mesmo que está no HTML. O que é dinâmico e muda consoante o que fôr escrito é a propriedade `.value`. Assim podes saber se o que está no input ainda é o original.

Comment: obrigado pelas opções

Answer (score 1):

Isso é muito simples de fazer com `HTML5`, basta adicionar um `placeholder` no seu `input` ou `textarea`, veja o exemplo:

```html
<span>Nome</span>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu Nome">
<br>
<br>

<span>Mensagem</span>
<br>
<textarea placeholder="Digite sua Mensagem"></textarea>
```

Simple like that!

Infelizmente só é aceito no IE 10+

Veja aqui o suporte:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder